# Firestore Security Rules: User with the same uid can write but it does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Current problem: User can **read** but can't **write**.

I confirmed that there are no errors in my Flutter code, and the uid account logged in is the same as the uid in the document. And when I only keep the "/{document=**}" match and change "write" to true, it works.

```js
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Securoty rules don't become active until you execute code against them. Please edit your question to show the minimal code which doesn't work against these rules too, and in that code **prove** that you're meeting the requirements of your rules (i.e. check that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is null null, and show that you're writing to `/users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid}`).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've uploaded my Flutter code.

Comment: It looks like you found the problem . Going forward, please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing `FirebaseFirestore.instance` to `FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: app)`.